# Ctypes Structures with Optional Members

Tags: python, c-preprocessor, ctypes

I have a C structure whose contents can vary depending on CPP defines like so.

```
typedef struct
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
    #if (SOMETIMES_TRUE)
    int optional;
    #end
    int baz;
    #if (SEPARATELY_SOMETIMES_TRUE)
    int more_options;
    #end
    int fuzz;
} my_fun_structure;
```

Previously the CPP lines evaluated to `FALSE` so I did not need to account for the optional fields. I use my ctypes definition to parse a binary file. Once they were enabled, my binary parser output resulted in mostly garbage.

I can workaround this by creating two ctype definitions of `my_fun_structure` but it is not at all maintainable. Especially when the structure's member offsets are very fluid.

I've heard of generating c-types dynamically, but I don't think it will suit me. This code base is large and definitions intermix across several (~40) files in several (~10) folders.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm stuck with?

Comment: The whole point of header files in C/C++ is to provide a single definition of things like `#define`s and `struct` layouts for inclusion in multiple files at compile time, so your claim that things are so fluid that it would make maintenance of two `ctype` definitions too difficult doesn't ring true.

Comment: The C/C++ ecosystem is designed for that, but Ctypes isn't as far as I can tell. Right now I am working with two `ctype` definitions in my **python** code. The definitions originate from their C counterparts. Sure that *can* be manageable, but I provided a very simplistic example. Generally I am working with cases where, for example, the above two are enabled/disabled in an independent fashion, resulting in up to 4 possible definitions. That is the nightmare I am hoping to avoid since in reality it would be much greater than that (say, 10-15 possibilities for a single structure).

Comment: You don't need to define every combination of possible resulting definition in advance. Python is very good at text processing and dynamic, so at runtime a text representation of the `ctypes` equivalent to the structure can be created and then called `eval()`, effectively mimicking the C++ preprocessor, In a somewhat similar situation, Python code actually parsed `,h` (or `.hpp`) headers and looked for `#define` directives in them to determine the values of control symbols. In another situation, Python code actually ran the cpp preprocessor and parsed its output.

Comment: You don't have to `eval` anything. The `_fields_` attribute of a `Structure` subclass is just a sequence. This could be managed with a master class for the shared library that gets instantiated with configuration options for how the library was built. This configuration in turn gets passed to init routines that define the structs and function prototypes for the library instance. Don't think in terms of static C definitions that need to be hacked with a preprocessor. Python is dynamic.

Comment: I'll give that a shot.

Comment: For what it's worth, @eryksun 's suggestion worked for me.